# Is there a wifi driver for AR5523 chipset, on linux kernel 3.2+?

Tags: atheros

I found this: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ar5523

But when I svn co and then try to compile it I get errors [errors here: http://pastebin.com/8BSvk9Ev ].  I don't think it was coded for linux kernel 3.2.x and I have 3.2.0-30-generic.

I tried to install ndiswrapper but when I run it I get:

```
# ndiswrapper
Error: unable to find a version of ndiswrapper!
```

so I've hit a wall, does anyone know how to get the driver for this Atheros wifi chipset? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the instructions found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9369514&postcount=4)?

Comment: @SirCharlo, yes I saw that post.  The problem is I get compiling errors on the command `m-a a-i ar5523-source` [See the pastebin]

Answer (score 1):

I found this have you looked at it yet? [Atheros AR5523 devices](http://wiki.debian.org/ar5523)

Hope it helps you.....Have an awesome day!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I already tried that.  `m-a` throws an error, and the log shows the compile failed.

Comment: @Matt Please add your attempt and log outputs/failures in your question. Then I can take a look at what goes wrong.

Comment: @gertvdijk, I have posted  a pastebin error log, have you read it? it's in the main question but here it is again: http://pastebin.com/8BSvk9Ev